# Could not resolve <s:View> to a component implementation

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, flex4.6

On projects that used to work just fine I'm now getting a, "Could not resolve  to a component implementation." error. It's preventing me from compiling them and I don't know what if anything has changed.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.actionScriptProperties
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

The general library has two excluded libraries:

```
    <excludedEntries>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/flex.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/core.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
    </excludedEntries>
```

The mobile only library has many excluded libraries:

```
    <excludedEntries>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/advancedgrids.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/qtp.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/automation_air.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/air/airspark.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/netmon.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/mx/mx.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/air/applicationupdater.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/utilities.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/flex.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/sparkskins.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/qtp_air.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/datavisualization.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/spark_dmv.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/automation.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/automation_dmv.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/automation_flashflexkit.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/air/applicationupdater_ui.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/air/airframework.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/automation_agent.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
    </excludedEntries>
```

Comment: Smells like you don't have the mobile libraries on your build path.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but I don't know how that happened. Is there a way I can check that? I mean I made the library a mobile library to begin with, maybe it lost that build path on upgrading or import.

Comment: An AIR project should only exclude `/libs/flex.swc`